# Having trouble php composer install IMAP missing - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, mamp

I'm having trouble getting the IMAP PHP module working on my mac. Trying to run Laravel app using MAMP. When I run the command `composer install` I get this error message below. Seem that IMAP is not installed or enabled.

The requested PHP extension IMAP is missing from your system

[image]

I tried a few things to resolve this issue but kept running into a loop.

I ran => `brew install kabel/php-ext/php@7.2-imap`

[image]

I ran => `composer require webklex/laravel-imap`

[image]

```
php -i | grep imap
```

[image]

PHP 7.1.23 (cli)

Mojave 10.14.5

I'm using MAMP

Comment: You are saying you are using PHP 7.1.23 (cli) but installed the IMAP-Extension for 7.2

Comment: I'm confused on how this setup works. When I use the command line I see php 7.1.23. When I check MAMP standard version I see php 7.3.1. I'm just trying to get it to work and when I run "composer install" this is the first error I get.  Problem 1
    - Installation request for webklex/laravel-imap 1.2.9 -> satisfiable by webklex/laravel-imap[1.2.9].
    - webklex/laravel-imap 1.2.9 requires ext-imap * -> the requested PHP extension imap is missing from your system.

Comment: My advice is to uninstall your MAMP and install php from brew

Comment: How is this related to Laravel after all?

Comment: It's probably not. I'm new to this and naming all possibilities I'm not sure, that's why I'm asking questions along with my tech list. So you know what I'm working with.

Comment: Got it working updating php brew install php@7.2. Thanks Muhammad advise and a little more research. https://vyspiansky.github.io/2018/11/08/set-up-php-7.2-on-macos-mojave-with-homebrew/ .  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

In your php.ini you will find a line like this `;extension=imap`

remove `;`

```
extension=imap
```

save your php.ini, restart apache and try again